# An Open Source Project, Can Teach Membership and Role Management For .NET

Tags: .net, open-source, asp.net-membership

I want to see a basic project to learn how to organize membership and role management. Can you give me some open source project link about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in an `asp.net` user membership example, 
[N2](http://n2cms.com/Features.aspx) has a feature named `User registration & Login parts`.

[N2](http://www.codeplex.com/n2) is an open source lightweight CMS framework. One benefit of it's modular and lightweight approach is that the CMS can be integrated into existing ASP.NET solutions and ASP.NET MVC.